# MYSQL update the only x'th number in integer/bit datatype field

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I created 9 columns each which hold either a 0 or a 1 integer. They exist so that users can toggle certain things on and off. I'd like to get rid of these 9 columns and instead use only one column where i can hold 9 0's and 1's for the 9 things my users will toggle. So say i have 000000000 and my user decides to toggle the first function, how would an update query for table `accounts` and column `toggletimers` look like which would change the value to 100000000 and so on for the 9 numbers?

Comment: You can use SET data type

Comment: check out the user comments here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You normally should *not* merge multiple fields into one in database design (violation of ["1NF"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form))
2. If you really want to, use the [bitwise operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html): `update accounts set toggletimers = toggletimers | (1 << (9-1)) where ...`